# Hide the info in application.properties in spring-boot when commiting to git

Tags: git, postgresql, gradle

In my sprint-boot application, there is the data to connect to a postgresql database on my personal computer but I don't want to put them on github. So I want to know how to hide them before commiting to git knowing that I use Gradle to build the application.

Answer (score 3):

Write the data to some file, add the file to `.gitignore` so that it does not get committed and then read the info from that file at runtime.

Or set the properties in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` or in `gradle.properties` in the root of your project and add it to `.gitignore` and then make Gradle replace some placeholder with the actual values at build time.

Comment: And what if I want to use Travis on github ? I still need the file so I cannot put it in gitignore.

Comment: What do you mean? You said you don't want the data on GitHub, now you say you need it on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Just add application.properties to your .gitignore file.